# How can I pass an array as parameter without using Brackets in Swift?

Tags: swift

I want to know how could I pass an array as parameter to function without using Brackets, like `print`in Swift. as you can see in down it can be 3 or 5 or 7 strings, it would work

```
print("1", "2", "3")
```

---

```
func customFunction(???) { }
```

Comment: See https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html You are looking for "Variadic Parameters", also called "Argument List", "Arg List".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this via **Variadic functions** this allows you to input parameter as comma separated values. just put 3 dots at the the end of parameter type

```
func customFunction(values: String...) {
    for value in values {
        print(value)
    }
}
```

function call

```
customFunction(values: "1", "2", "3")
```